# Catch refresh and change page to index.html

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

i have a question. I want to detect, if a user has pressed F5 or the refresh button. If so, i want to change the page to index.html. Here is my code:

```
$(window).on('beforeunload',function(){

    $.mobile.changePage($(document.location.href="/index.html"),{
        transition:"slide",
        changeHash:false
    });

});
```

But it's not working. Has anybody a solution, how i can achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just get the key value:

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
if(e.which == 116) {
    window.location.href = '/index.html'; 
}
});
```

[Key Reference](http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes)

Alternative method:

```
document.onkeydown = fkey;
document.onkeypress = fkey
document.onkeyup = fkey;

 var wasPressed = false;

 function fkey(e){
    e = e || window.event;
   if( wasPressed ) return; 

    if (e.keyCode == 116) {
         window.location.href = '/index.html'; 
        wasPressed = true;
    }else {
        alert("Window closed");
    }
 }
```

Comment: @Bleistift try my alternative method

Comment: the same result as before. My location is still  localhost:8080/second.html

Comment: @Bleistift can you tell me what is the path of you index.html ?

Comment: @Bleistift is the path is  localhost:8080/index.html

Comment: @Bleistift are you getting any error in your console?

Comment: @Bleistift then can you show me your full code,from beginning to end? beco'z it's work perfectly for me

Comment: i think i know wheres the problem. I create my html dymanically and if i refresh my page i stay on that page where i refresh. I have to check on which page my refresh was catched. thx for your help priyank!